# How can I read a type name from a DocumentDB document model from within a generic DocumentDBRepository?

Tags: c#, azure, generics, repository, azure-cosmosdb

I have a DocumentDB collection with heterogenous document types.  My DocumentDB repository is based on [this GitHub project](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-net/blob/master/tutorials/todo/src/DocumentDBRepository.cs), and has `GetItems` methods as follows:

```
    public IReadOnlyCollection<T> GetItems()
    {
        return Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Collection.DocumentsLink).ToList();
    }

    public T GetItem(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Collection.DocumentsLink)
            .Where(predicate)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The repository works well, but using the above queries all of my documents are returned when I actually want to query by type.

Several sources (such as [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/39hxav/i_work_on_the_azure_documentdb_team_ama/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091731/querying-poco-entities-from-documentdb)) suggest using a type attribute built into my DocumentModels, so I have updated my `BaseDocument` class (from which all documents inherit) to include a type.  `BaseDocument` now looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class BaseDocument
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public BaseDocument(string id, string type)
    {
        Id = id;
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

I have tried changing my GetItems methods to include the type string as follows:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<T> GetItems(string type)
{    
    return Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Collection.DocumentsLink,
        String.Format("SELECT * FROM collection c WHERE c.type = '{0}'", type)).ToList();
}
```

This works, but it seems clumsy to have to pass through magic strings each time I call `GetItems()`.  I figure I could include a constant within each `FooDocument` (each of which extends `BaseDocument`) that would specify the type name, but I don't know how to read it without passing it through.  How could I read this constant from within my `DocumentDbRepository<FooDocument>` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a public get property to the BaseDocument that returns the type
Something like (pseudo code here so bear with me);

```
public string Type
    get {
        return this.GetType() // you can control if you want the FQN or just the name
    }
```

Add on the following to the end of the GetItems method signature

```
where T : BaseDocument
```

Now you can do something like this in your repo;

```
    return Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(Collection.DocumentsLink,
    String.Format("SELECT * FROM collection c WHERE c.type = '{0}'", T.Type)).ToList();
```

This gets rid of the need for a constant and you don't have to pass type around as a parameter to your methods.

You can even do the following with LINQ;

```
GetItems<T>(Predicate predicate) Where T : BaseDocument {
    return client.CreateDocumentQuery(collectionLink)
                .Where(predicate)
                .Where(d => d.Type == T.Type);
}
```

I have a working repo that does this if you would like I can share / post somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can work this out from your from your answer, but if you could add a link to a github project or something, that would be great!